# ntfsfix can't come to an end

Tags: ntfs

After I executed:

`ntfsfix /dev/sda1`

It gets stuck.

The last output line in the Terminal is:

```
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
```

And a blinking cursor.

Mounting ro is possible, File system seems to be OK but Windows can't start.

:

```
root@sysresccd /root % ntfsfix /dev/sda1
Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to sync device /dev/sda1: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Failed to sync device /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Failed to fsync device /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda1 was processed successfully.
Failed to sync device /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Failed to fsync device /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Failed to unmount partition
root@sysresccd /root %
```

Booting a windows rescue cd and executing something resutls in errors. Chkdsk in an I/O error.

The disk is a SSD an in good conditions (CrystalDiskInfo)

Comment: IMHO you should only fix ntfs partitions from windows, the tools in Linux are suboptimal.

Comment: But I can't access the partition from a windows environment!

Comment: If you can't access the partition from a windows environment you should not use NTFS for these reasons. Is sda1 mounted ? Is the hard drive failing ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and wanted to emphasize the occurrence of `Failed to sync device /dev/sda1: Input/output error` here. Also, When trying `chkdisk` via a windows recovery disk, it told me that chkdisk can not be run on RAW partitions.

Answer (score 1):

`ntfsfix /dev/sdX` is used to fix any potential errors on your drive, the complete output of that command should be something similar to this:

```
Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors...
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdc1 was processed successfully.
```

If you're stuck in `Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK`, this could mean that the command is still `Checking the alternate boot sector... OK`, I recommend you to wait, this task could take some time depending on your hard drive.

Also, if you know that your hard drive may have bad sectors, then here is your answer: [Corrupt NTFS filesystem causes ntfsfix to hang](https://superuser.com/questions/923023/corrupt-ntfs-filesystem-causes-ntfsfix-to-hang)

Another option is to check your hard drive with the command `chkdsk` from a Windows machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "is used to fix any potential errors" Eh, if only it were true! `ntfsfix` checks almost nothing compared to Windows `chkdsk`. Regarding the alternate boot sector, it is only 512 bytes in size. It can't take that long to check, there must be some other issue.